# Select dropdownlist item after button click

Tags: vb.net, button, drop-down-menu, click

I have an asp drowndownlist and I'd like to change its selection after a button click. I can't seem to find a way to do this, is there a way? (Its a reset button of sorts, and I would like the dropdownlist to return to the "default" value.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DropDownList.SelectedIndex = -1`

Comment: Doesn't this assume that the top Item is the default one?

Comment: No. Because the index is zero-based, the item at index 0 could be a valid selection. Setting SelectedIndex to -1 means nothing is selected. Or that's my understanding anyways.

Answer (score 0):

In the click event can you do:

```
DropDownList.SelectedItem = "whatever";
DropDownList.DataBind()
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
dropdownlist.ClearSelection()
```